# Scroll won't appear or cuts off the bottom? (Tumblr Theme)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tumblr

When using a tumblr theme, I added an extra row for links, but the page won't automatically scroll. When changing the position to absolute, they scroll, but it doesn't show all the way, nor do the titles scroll. Can anyone help me out with this?

I'm not such what to change/add/remove to have the page scroll properly with the titles moving too.

The original code is [here](http://pastebin.com/pQhKJXT4).

And [here](http://pastebin.com/7iYzqxbT) is the code once I added the last row.

The person who made the theme has deactivated their blog and their credit link leads to some odd site, so asking them for help isn't that easy considering I have no way of reaching them.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go for a structure change. Currently because of position: absolute it is difficult to overflow the content in a standard way.

Ideally you should do the following

- wrap the  following series () in a parent
  and style it to be on the right hand side and add the style
  **overflow: scroll** to it.
- remove the #columni {margin-left: 530px;} instead make it
  display:inline-block;
- remove the #columnsi{position: absolute;}